# How to retrieve the source code of the native macOS bundle generated by NetBeans for a JavaFX application?

Tags: javafx-8, netbeans-8, macos-sierra

I have a JavaFX 8 application with a preloader, which works nicely on Windows, Linux and macOS.

I'm currently using NetBeans to package my app into a native macOS bundle, which give me the required folder tree for the application and the embedded JRE, along with a default content for Info.plist and an automatically compiled native executable, which is used to launch my app with the embedded JRE.

The thing is I don't want to be tied to NetBeans to generate this bundle. And the only thing that prevents me to be independent from NetBeans is that automatically compiled native executable, for which I don't have the source code.

I tried to browse NetBeans source code to find how this native executable is generated to no avail. Does anybody have any idea about how it's generated?

Comment: All it is doing, ultimately, is invoking the `javapackager` command (which is part of the standard JDK), probably via an Ant task. You can just invoke that yourself from the command line (or make a build process in your favorite IDE; many already come with tools to do that). See the [deployment guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/).

Comment: Thanks for the useful tip! So ultimately, I have to look at what javapackager is doing. My goal is to package everything from my main computer on Windows. A friend is lending me his MacBook but I can't work permanently on a lent machine...

Comment: You could use https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin or https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin ;) and yes, I'm the maintainer/creator of these projects

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to cross-package your appliction from Windows to Mac, then I have to disappoint you because this is currently not prossible with the JavaFX packager.